# Распределение запросов по директориям

Tags: node.js, express

У меня есть приложение. В котором дефолтно обьявленно `var app = express();` И есть разные пост и гет запросы. `app.get('/cancel', (req, res) => res.redirect('/failedbuy'));` Типа такого. Я хотел бы узнать возможно ли перенести в другие файлы для уменьшение строк в первичном файле и как устроить такую маршрутизацию. Я знаю, что с функциями есть `module.exports.` А вот с запросами не знаю как поступать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Лучше всего декомпозицию выполнять через Router.

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
module.exports = router;
```

В таком случае запросы можно отправлять как `router.get`

Answer (score 1):

можно объявить такую функцию:

```
var cancelHandler = (req, res) => res.redirect('/failedbuy');
```

и обработчик маршрута будет выглядеть таким образом:

```
app.get('/cancel', cancelHandler);
```

и эту функцию `cancelHandler` можно вынести в другой файл и импортировать там где нужно.